# fadeIn a div with a click, but then click anywhere to hide an element

Tags: jquery

I followed almost any previously asked questions but I couldn't figure it out.

I have got such a simple welcome page containing a few lines. In that content there are 2 links to show some informations below (Those informations are hidden by CSS). When you click any of them you can see it below, and the Jquery hides the other one. It works fine.

But I need to hide them when I click anywhere:

To see mine in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Tks5L/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var container = $('#info_area');
    $('#contentart span').click(function () {
        var active = $(container.find('div')[$(this).prevAll('span').length]);
        active.siblings().hide();
        active.fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

and html

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
     <section id="headerall">
        <header>Welcome</header>
          <div class="clr"></div>   
     </section>
                   <div class="clr"></div>
     <section id="content">
       <article id="contentart">
          <p id="contentp">
             content content content content content content content conten content content content; fade in link 1 <span class="mailgsminfo1">info 1</span> or or or <span class="mailgsminfo2">info 2</span> content text content text.<br /> Thanks
          </p>
                   <div class="clr"></div>
       </article>
       <article id="info_area">
         <div class="info1"><span class="title">info 1:</span> info 1 must show here</div>
         <div class="info1"><span class="title">info 2:</span> info 2 must show here</div>
       </article>
     </section>

         <div class="clr"></div>

</div> <!-- Wrap ende -->
</body>
```

Could you help me how to hide my those info parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like that:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tks5L/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.info1').css('outline',0).attr('tabindex', -1).on('focusout', function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });

    var container = $('#info_area');

    $('#contentart span').click(function () {
        var active = $(container.find('div')[$(this).prevAll('span').length]);
        active.siblings().hide();
        active.fadeIn("slow").focus();


    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help roasted. Your one seems a bit more complexed, containing the css inside the Jquery but I will study it, too!

Comment: You could put CSS outside of javascript of course. The idea was to avoid any delegated event to document level as usually its a practice to avoid. Using pXl's answer, each time you will click anywhere in the document, this will fire function binded to document even no info1 element is in use.

Comment: Hi again roasted. I've just tried yours and I see that it seems better. At least it allows me to copy any info appeared there with the mouse, it doesn't disappear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to hide info

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('#contentart span')) {
        $('#info_area div').hide();
    }
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/Tks5L/3/